# what does KEY slug(slug) means in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
 CREATE TABLE news (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title varchar (128) NOT NULL,
    slug varchar (128) NOT NULL,
    text text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY slug (slug)
    );
```

What does KEY slug (slug) means in the above code?

Answer (score 5):

```
KEY slug (slug)
```

Here KEY means index, first slug is a index name (you can skip it or keep it), (slug) means creating index on slug field.

As a standard you keep keep it as-

```
KEY idx_slug(slug)
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) lead me to this:

`{INDEX|KEY}`

So in this case it is referring to the fact that `KEY` is an `INDEX` on the table, and it doesn't refer to a primary key or foreign key.

In the context of this line, `KEY slug (slug)`, it is creating an index called slug on the slug field.

Answer (score -1):

Key slug is used to store the unique key that would be used to route to fetch your information in codeigniter you can use it by configuring the slug class